# on AJAX request fade in with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a form that inserts data into my DB using AJAX and PHP.

***AJAX***

```
function insertBill()
{
    $.post('insert_bill.php', $('#insertbill').serialize(), 
        function(data) {
        $('#bills').append(data);
    });
};
```

Is it possible using jQuery to have my data fade into the #bills div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following in different variations:

```
function insertBill() {
    $.post('insert_bill.php', $('#insertbill').serialize(), 
        function(data) {
        $('#bills').hide().append(data).fadeIn("slow");
    });
}
```

You could also have #Bills hidden via css on load of site or you could hide it on submit as follows:

```
function insertBill() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'insert_bill.php',
        data: $('#insertbill').serialize(),
        type: 'post', 
        beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) {
            $('#bills').hide();
        },
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $('#bills').append(data).fadeIn("slow");
        },
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#bills').hide().append(data).fadeIn(400);
```